# Detect a when a client disconnects from the server

Tags: java, sockets, java-io

How to detect when a client disconnects from a server that is using ServerSocket and Socket?

I have an Object I/O Stream. When the client disconnects, I want to server to decrease the currently running connections and show a message. This must happen at more or less the exact time of disconnecting. How do you get this?

Comment: It can't happen at 'more or less the exact time of disconnecting'. It can only happen when you read from the connection and detect an end of stream. If you aren't reading, you won't detect it. If the read is delayed by other processing, you will detect it after the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can detect the end-of-stream when the corresponding read operation returns -1 (for raw read() calls), or null (for readLine() calls), or throw `EOFException` (for all other `readXXX()` calls).

Socket methods will cause a `SocketException: socket closed` when performed on a closed socket. This indicates a programming error on your part.

There is one more solution to this problem is to exchange heartbeat periodically between two connected entity, most of the telecommunication system uses this approach to respond disconnection.

Comment: Completely incorrect. isConnected() doesn't change state when the peer disconnects. That's not what it's for. It tells you whether you have ever connected *this Socket.* it doesn't tell you about the state of the connection. Same applies to isBound() and isClosed(). They tell you about the local socket state, not the connection state. -1

Comment: @EJP, after your comment I researched more and come t know that you are right so updating my answer. Thanks for updating my knowledge base

Comment: Fixed it some more for you. I'm not sure about this 'updating my knowledge base' stuff. The statement was always incorrect, it isn't new.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to read or write something then you will get to know. Detect this by performing a read(), which will either return -1 (EOF) or raise a SocketException ("connection reset").

Comment: Or return null in the case of readLine(), or throw an EOFException in the case of readObject(), readInt(), readUTF(), etc.